# What is this small white insect on my plants?

Tags: botany, entomology

### Environment

I have a large amount of plants in an old industrial loft apartment.

I live in Rochester, New York.

I ship plants in from across the US, often exotic ones.

### Observations

A few months ago, I noticed that two of my Sarracenia plants in my carnivorous plant bog were not growing anymore. Upon cutting them out as to not disrupt the live sphagnum moss grow medium, I noted that one of the insects in question had burrowed its way down into the core of the plant. I assume this to be the cause of the growing issue.

Today I noticed that one of my grape plants and Colocasia plants were covered in these bugs at different stages of growth. They range from white specs to ~3mm with the tail thing.

These insects appear sedentary. I have never seen one move, except when I cut the one out of the center of the plant.

Here is a picture of the bug, which was difficult to get due to the size.

[image]

### Research

I looked through a variety of different "common insect" sites as well as some insect identification sites but I was unable to find anything remotely similar.

I have only elementary knowledge of insects. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mealybug; don't know much about them.